# pandas to dict: to_dict does not store all values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df` with 40000 rows:

```
              0  bin
0      4.506840  4-5
1      4.506840  4-5
2      4.444245  4-5
3      4.485975  4-5
4      4.527705  4-5
...         ...  ...
39995  6.572475  6-7
39996  6.697665  6-7
39997  6.322095  6-7
39998  6.322095  6-7
39999  6.676800  6-7
```

It stores for every number in column '0' the interval (bin) it belongs to. 
I want to convert it to a dict by:

```
dict(zip(df[0],df.bin))
```

to get an output like:

```
{4.506840: '4-5', 4.506840: '4-5', 4.444245: '4-5, ... }
```

so I want to store every value from '0' and the bin it belongs to. 
Somehow my dict has a length of 340, not 40000, so it doesn't store all of the rows. My question is: why? And how do I get all 40000 rows in the dict? Cheers!

Comment: you have duplicate keys which a dictionary cannot have, what is `len(df[0].unique())` ? 1 way is probably groupby on the first column and aggregate the second as a list depending on your requirement then save as dict

Comment: thanks for the help. The fact that I didn't recognize there were doublets is that the data displayed in '0' is shorten. Instead of 4.506840 the true value is 4.506840169429779, the second one 4.506840143557677. But anyway there are still same values a few rows later. I didn't think this would be possible due to so many digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the duplicates you have in your `df[0]`, and due to the fact that you cannot have the same key duplicated in a python dictionary, you can do:

```
result = {}
for i_0, i_bin in zip(df[0],df.bin):
    if i_0 not in result.keys():
        result[i_0] = []
    result[i_0].append(i_bin)
```

output:

```
{
    "4.506840": ["4-5", "4-5"],
    "4.444245": ["4-5"],
    ...
}
```

It depends on what you want to achieve, but this is a way to perceive all the values.

**Edit:**

As per @anky comment, you can make use of pandas aggregation function to do the same instead of the loop. Definitely, it is of better performance:

```
df.groupby(0)['bin'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have multiple values in that column that are the same, and altough python allows you to store multiple values that are the same, you can't store more than one of the same key. I would suggest either you don't use a dict or try to put some identifier on each duplicate in the df before converting it into a dict to distinguish it from other keys. Another way would be to divide the df where the duplicates are or store all the duplicates in a list, although I'm not sure this is what you desire.

Comment: Not perhaps! He already has duplicates :) For example, check the first two rows.

Comment: Correct sir! Should it be noted, I'm not very sure that using dicts is the correct approach here.